# Error Upgrading magento 2.0.7 to magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2

I'm having an error upgrading my magento 2.0.7 to magento 2.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just in the composer.json, It seems that the composer.json of the site I'm handling does not have that line. That's why after adding that line to the composer.json it successfully ugpraded the site to magento 2.1.1

[image]